# How to perform a calculation that triggers interrupt 0 without using the "int" command.?

Tags: assembly, x86, interrupt, interrupt-handling

I´m trying to solve this but I don't know how to start. If someone could give advice how to think about this task it would be great.

```
hello db "Hello!",0
hello_len equ $-hello 

section .text
start:
; EXERCISE: 
;   TASK: register isr0 for interrupt 0
;   QUESTION: which command triggers an interrupt
cli ; 
;---- fill in your code below ---

;---- fill in your code above ---
sti ; 

; call ISR for interrupt 0 
int 0

; EXERCISE: 
;   TASK:; perform a calculation that triggers interrupt 0 without using the "int" command.
;   QUESTION: why is it looping?
;---- fill in your code below ---

;---- fill in your code above ---

halt: ; stop cpu and wait for interrupts
hlt
jmp halt

isr0:
mov bx,hello
mov cx,hello_len - 1
call output

iret
```

The output declaration:

```
push bp       ;
mov bp,sp     ; mov adress from sp to bp 

push bp       ; save current bp
mov bp, bx    ; move string start address to bp 

xor bx, bx    ; bx = 0
mov es, bx    ; es = bx = 0

mov ah, 0x13  ; use function 13h
mov al, 0x01  ; mode 1

mov bl, 0x07  ; color: white
mov bh, 0x00  ; screen page 0

mov dl, 0x00  ; set column
mov dh, [line] ; set line
inc byte [line] ;

int 0x10 

pop bp        ; restore bp

leave  
ret  

section .magic start=(org_address + 510)
db 0x55
db 0xaa
```

Comment: Is this your homework? What did you try, did you execute the code? I would start [reading about interrupts](https://service.scs.carleton.ca/sivarama/asm_book_web/Student_copies/ch12_interrupts.pdf). Then I would write behind each statement what it does - maybe as comment [like here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/assembly_basic_syntax.htm) (lookup  _mnemonic_ you don't know).

Comment: I don't see declaration of _macro_ `output`. Does the code compile?

Comment: Yes. The Code doesnt execute . I missed the output declaration . Is it possible to repost this Code here ? I´m totally new into this.

Comment: @PeterCordes see https://stackoverflow.com/legal/acceptable-use-policy on how to remove copyrighted content. Please do not vandalise the question in the meantime.

Answer (score 3):

Interrupt number 0 is the divide exception, `#DE`.  (https://wiki.osdev.org/Interrupt_Vector_Table)

Any integer division where the quotient doesn't fit in the operand-size will raise it.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/div or `idiv`.  Or even [`aam 0`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/aam) - divide by an immediate zero.

Fun fact: being synchronous, it will still fire when interrupts are disabled.  (Although in your template you're only disabling interrupts around modifying the IVT, I guess.)

Fun fact #2: if you were in protected mode, `int 0` wouldn't be equivalent to divide by zero.  The IDT descriptor applies different privilege level in that case.  See [Why linux kernel use trap gate to handle divide_error exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8530794/why-linux-kernel-use-trap-gate-to-handle-divide-error-exception/15501983#15501983) for an example.

Comment: Divide by zero throws the exception too.

Comment: @ecm: In that case the quotient is infinite, so doesn't fit in any fixed-width base 2 integer.  I was intentionally being slightly vague because this is a homework question, and I wanted to encourage the OP to read the manual for `div` where they can see that, too.  But my last paragraph does mention divide by zero.

Comment: Yeah, and you do mention divide by zero in the second paragraph too, just only in the context of `aam`. I think division by zero is specifically an exception because it is not considered a valid operation, so I find it a bit odd to state "the quotient is infinite". Sure, in some sense it is, but not universally.

Comment: @ecm: That's just weak justification for being vague on purpose, not much of a real argument. :P