# Is the abrupt ending of a process using Control + C a trap or an interrupt?

Tags: c, linux, process, signals, interrupt

It seems as though the [difference between a trap and an interrupt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149175/what-is-the-difference-between-trap-and-interrupt) is clear: a trap is a software-invoked call to the kernel (such as through an exception) and an interrupt is pertinent to the hardware (the disk, I/O and peripheral devices such as the mouse and the keyboard...) (learn more about [the difference here](http://www.differencebetween.com/difference-between-interrupt-and-vs-trap/)).

Knowing this, under what category should pressing Control + C to end a process be classified? Is it a software-invoked call and thus a trap since it can be executed from the Shell, etc. or is it an interrupt since it's a signal that the CPU receives from the keyboard? Or are interrupts wholly outside users' domain, meaning that it's the hardware interacting with the CPU at a level that the user cannot reach?

Thank you!

Comment: It is an interrupt!!!

Comment: @shekharsuman Please do not badger askers into accepting your answer. That's rude.

Comment: @Gilles- Actually I am fed of unaccepted answers on SO! That's why!!! But,don't you think that answers satisfying OP must be accepted by him? You might be already aware by my nature through operating system Stack Exchange forum in which I requested to consider viewing my accepted answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between a trap and an interrupt is not as you described in your question (thanks for the reference) but to the asynchronous nature of the events producing it.  A trap means an interrupt in the code execution due to a normally incorrect/internal operation (like dividing by zero or a page fault, or as you signaled, a software interrupt), but it ocurrs always at the same place in the code (synchronously with the code execution)  and an interrupt occurs because of external hardware, when some device signals the cpu to interrupt what it is doing, as it's ready to send some data.  By nature, traps are synchronous and interrupts aren't.

Said this, both are anomalous events that change the normal course of execution of the cpu.  Both are **hardware** produced, but for different reasons: the first occurs synchronously (you know always *when*, in which instruction, it will be produced, if produced at all) and the second not (you don't know in advance which instruction will be executing when external hardware would assert the interrupt line)  Also, there are two kinds of traps (depending on the event that triggered them), one puts the instruction pointer pointing to the next instruction (for example a divide by zero trap) to be executed, and the other puts it pointing to the same instruction that caused the trap (for example a page fault, that has to be reexecuted once the cause of the trap has been corrected)  Of course, software interrupts, as by their nature, are always traps (traps that always change the course of execution) as it can be predicted the exact point in the program flow where the cpu will get interrupted.

So, with this explanation, you probably can answer your question yourshelf, a **Ctrl-C** interrupt is an *interrupt* as you cannot predice in advance when it will interrupt the cpu execution and you cannot mark that point in your code.

Remember, interrupts ocurr asynchronously, traps not.

Answer (score 6):

It's first and foremost a **signal** — pressing Control-C causes the kernel to send a signal (of type SIGINT) to the current foreground process. If that process hasn't set up a handler for that signal (using one of the system calls from the `signal()` family), it causes the process to be killed.

The signal is, I suppose, the "interrupt" signal, but this is unrelated to hardware interrupts. Those are only used internally by the kernel.

Comment: Actually it's a kind of software interrupt! Interrupts can be of sofware type also...

Comment: sorry, but there are **signals** that are traps in unix... for example a SIGSEGV is a trap, it occurs synchronously in the code (always you try to make an invalid memory access)  See my answer to the question below (or above, don't know).

Answer (score 2):

The pressing of `Ctrl+C` on Linux systems is used to kill a process with the signal `SIGINT`, and can be intercepted by a program so it can clean its self up before exiting, or not exit at all.

Had it been a trap, it'd have got instantaneously died!

Hence,it is a kind of a software interrupt!

Comment: Can interrupts always be intercepted by the program whereas traps can't? Thanks, Shekhar

Comment: Sorry,it's unclear to me.Would you mind elaborating somewhat @miguel5! Which programs are you referring to!

Comment: I mean any user-level program (not the kernel, etc.)! Thank you!

Comment: Interrupta are not as stable,means as quick responsive as the traps are. Even the `SIGINT` signal is sent, the killing of process isn't  so quick and may take time. Whereas, if a process falls in a trap, it'll become unresponsive as the trap is hardware specific issue!

Answer (score 1):

Control-C is not an interrupt... at least not on the PC (and now MAC) hardware. In other words, the keyboard controller doesn't generate a specific interrupt for the key combination "control" and "C".

The keyboard uses only one interrupt vector which is triggered on a key down and a key up. The keyboard is an extremely slow hardware device. With the key repeat rate set to the fastest, holding down a key generate 33 interrupt per second.

If the designer of the operating system believe that control-C is extremely important, they may include the test "is this the key down for "C" AND is the "control" key triggered a keyboard interrupt some billions machine cycle ago? Then, while still processing the keyboard interrupt, they would generate a trap using a software interrupt instruction.

A better operating system would reduce the processing time of the keyboard interrupt to the strict minimum. They would just append to a circular buffer (ring buffer) the key code which include the bit pressed/released and immediately terminate the interrupt.

The operating system would then, whenever it has time, notice the change in ring buffer pointer. It would trigger the code which extract the key code from the ring buffer, verify if that code represent the "ctrl-C" combination and set a flag saying "ctrl-C" detected.

Finally, when the scheduler is ready to run a thread that belong to the current process, it check the flag "ctrl-C' detected. If it is the case, the scheduler set PC to point to the SIGINT routine instead of resuming to the previous execution address.

No matter the detail, "ctrl-C" can not be an interrupt. It is either a trap if called from the keyboard interrupt or it is a synchronization object tested asynchronously by the scheduler.