# What does a trap instruction do in an operating system?

Tags: operating-system

While studying operating systems concepts, I saw the term trap instruction.
"A TRAP instruction is performed to switch from
user mode to kernel mode." I failed to understand what a trap instruction does.

Comment: Have an explanation on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trap_%28computing%29).

Answer (score 9):

There are two ways to enter kernel mode:

1. Interrupt
2. Exception

When either occurs, the processor dispatches to the appropriate handler in its interrupt dispatch table (or similar mechanism). This table is defined by the operating system.

A trap is an exception where the instruction cannot be restarted. In contrast, a fault is an exception where the instruction can be restarted.

Every processor I am aware of has some instruction that explicitly causes an exception in order to get into kernel mode. Such instructions are used to implement operating system services.

Answer (score 2):

A trap is an exception in a user process. It's caused by division by zero or invalid memory access. It's also the usual way to invoke a kernel routine (a system call) because those run with a higher priority than user code. Handling is synchronous (so the user code is suspended and continues afterward). In a sense they are "active" - most of the time, the code expects the trap to happen and relies on this fact.

This answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149175/what-is-the-difference-between-trap-and-interrupt) might help.

---

I will give you an example to understand when to use **`fork`**  and what it does.

`fork` duplicates almost all to the newly created child in this process. There is a duplication of `trapframe` from parent to child. You may ask what the `trapframe` is: It's a way to ensure that both the parent and the child complete running from the place you called `fork`, so at the end both child and parent running this operation happen in kernel.

At the end, trap is to move to a permission place called kernel space. Every process has its own kernel space and in memory we have one kernel no duplication.

Comment: Well, a little fixing of word order would not mind. It is a little hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 different meanings for "trap instructions":

1. Interrupted instructions (for example, I/O interrupted instructions);
2. Processor exception (for example, [Data Abort](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0056/d/handling-processor-exceptions/about-processor-exceptions) (ARM), this exception occurs when a data transfer instruction attempts to load or store data at an illegal address.