# Example of how to implement a trap

Tags: linux, file, linux-kernel, operating-system, system-calls

I am taking an operating systems course. I have just learned about [traps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3149217).

> A trap is an exception in a user process. It's caused by division by
> zero or invalid memory access. It's also the usual way to invoke a
> kernel routine (a system call) because those run with a higher
> priority than user code

I would like to see how traps are implemented, but every source I can find on traps discusses them in the abstract.  Are traps implemented in Assembly or C? **Can you give example code that implements a trap?**

The part of the trap I am most interested in is how I would begin writing my own system calls. An ideal example would be a trap that executes when you want to read a file in Linux.

Comment: I'm afraid this is way too broad to answer. You can check out ["System Calls" on the OSDev wiki](https://wiki.osdev.org/System_Calls) to start learning something about how syscalls can be implemented.

Comment: Also look at processor manuals to see how the CPU can handle various types of exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Specifically in x86 trap is implemented as an assembly instruction with opcode `ud2`. This is seen in the linux kernel under the macro `BUG()` that is defined in [/arch/x86/include/asm/bug.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/d6ecaa0024485effd065124fe774de2e22095f2d/arch/x86/include/asm/bug.h#L66)

```c
#define ASM_UD2     ".byte 0x0f, 0x0b"
#define INSN_UD2    0x0b0f
#define LEN_UD2     2
...
#define BUG()                           \
do {                                \
    instrumentation_begin();                \
    _BUG_FLAGS(ASM_UD2, 0, "");             \
    __builtin_unreachable();                \
} while (0)
```

In GCC there is also a builtin called `__builtin_trap()` that inserts an opcode `ud2`.

[Godbolt Link](https://godbolt.org/z/nz4PG5ajz)

```c
void doit( int j) {
    if ( j<0 ) {
        __builtin_trap();
    }
}
```

produces

```
doit(int):                               # @doit(int)
        test    edi, edi
        js      .LBB0_1
        ret
.LBB0_1:
        ud2
```

Sanitizers also use trap explicitly to force an abort or stop in the debugger. [Clang Link](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer.html#usage)

Comment: *"Specifically in x86 trap is implemented as an assembly instruction with opcode ud2"* - well, not really. A "trap" is a generic concept. The `ud2` instruction will cause an invalid opcode exception, which you could consider a kind of "trap", for which the OS will usually have an exception handler ready. No OS uses `ud2` as a way to implement system calls though, that'd make little to no sense.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli  Fair. But gcc uses the name `__builtin_trap()` for a reason.