# What exactly is a trap?

Tags: operating-system, trap

From what I understand, there are software interrupts and hardware interrupts. Software interrupts include exception and trap, where a trap is called explicitly (such as in the case of systemcalls) and exceptions are called implicitly (such as in the case of division by 0, page fault, etc)

Am I right?
Are traps only used for systemcalls?

All the explanations I've read seem to contradict each other.

Comment: looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149175/what-is-the-difference-between-trap-and-interrupt

Answer (score 0):

There is no consistent terminology. Different architectures/vendors use those words to mean different things.

For example, on Motorola 68000 traps are exceptions called by `trap` or `trapv` instructions. They are called explicitly, like you said, however they are still considered exceptions - because Motorola calls all interrupts "exceptions".

On x86, exceptions are the first 32 reserved interrupts - they can be implicitly called by the CPU. They are further divided into traps, faults and aborts:

- **Trap** always happen at the end of instruction, next instruction address is saved. Returning from interrupt goes to the next instruction.
- **Fault** happens at the beginning of the instruction, current instruction address is saved. Returning from interrupt tries to run the instruction again.
- **Abort** is non-recoverable, you should not return from that interrupt.

On x86, any interrupt (including hardware and reserved ones) can be explicitly called in software. The `syscall` instruction is not considered an interrupt at all.